# Ошибка "name not defined"

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
def create_tabl_random(n):
    global tabl
    tabl = []
    for i in range(n):
        tabl.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            tabl[i].append(random.randint(0, 1))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j:
                tabl[i][j] = 0
            else:
                tabl[i][j] = tabl[j][i]
    return tabl


def window():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.title("Матриця суміжності")
    top.minsize(700, 600)

    def random_gen():
        global tabl
        tabl = create_tabl_random(int(ent.get()))
        for i in range(int(ent.get())):
            for j in range(int(ent.get())):
                list_ent[i][j].insert(END, tabl[i][j])

    r = 1
    c = 1
    for m in range(int(ent.get())):
        lab = Label(top, text=m, bg="papaya whip", font=("Arial", 18), width=3)
        lab.grid(row=r, column=0)
        r += 1
    for n in range(int(ent.get())):
        lab = Label(top, text=n, bg="papaya whip", font=("Arial", 18), width=3)
        lab.grid(row=0, column=c)
        c += 1
    list_ent = []
    for i in range(int(ent.get())):
        list_ent.append([])
        for j in range(int(ent.get())):
            list_ent[i].append(Entry(top, font=("Arial", 18), bg="floral white", width=3))
            list_ent[i][j].grid(row=i + 1, column=j + 1, sticky=W)
    Button(top, text='Згенерувати випадково', font=("Arial", 18), command=random_gen).grid(row=1, column=int(ent.get()) + 1, pady=10)
Nmax = len(tabl)
```

на последней строчке выбивает ошибку

```
line 54, in <module>
    Nmax = len(tabl)
NameError: name 'tabl' is not defined
```

Мне нужно достать из этих всех функции переменную tabl чтобы продолжить с ней работать
Перепробовал уже сто разных вариантов и все равно ошибка
Буду благодарен за любую помощь 
[image: Вот фото, чтобы было понятно, что я делаю]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: @gil9red, мне дальше нужно работать с моей таблицей (tabl), но я не понимаю как мне ее достать из этих функций

Comment: @Ivan почему бы вам просто не сделать класс и иметь self.tabl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял код тк не знаю импортов, но, наверное, что-то на подобие этого может вам помочь

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tabl = None

    def create_tabl_random(self, n):
        self.tabl = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.tabl.append([])
            for j in range(n):
                self.tabl[i].append(random.randint(0, 1))
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i == j:
                    self.tabl[i][j] = 0
                else:
                    self.tabl[i][j] = self.tabl[j][i]
        return self.tabl

    def window(self):
        top = Toplevel(root)
        top.title("Матриця суміжності")
        top.minsize(700, 600)

        def random_gen(self):
            create_tabl_random(int(ent.get()))
            for i in range(int(ent.get())):
                for j in range(int(ent.get())):
                    list_ent[i][j].insert(END, self.tabl[i][j])

        r = 1
        c = 1
        for m in range(int(ent.get())):
            lab = Label(top, text=m, bg="papaya whip",
                        font=("Arial", 18), width=3)
            lab.grid(row=r, column=0)
            r += 1
        for n in range(int(ent.get())):
            lab = Label(top, text=n, bg="papaya whip",
                        font=("Arial", 18), width=3)
            lab.grid(row=0, column=c)
            c += 1
        list_ent = []
        for i in range(int(ent.get())):
            list_ent.append([])
            for j in range(int(ent.get())):
                list_ent[i].append(
                    Entry(top, font=("Arial", 18), bg="floral white", width=3))
                list_ent[i][j].grid(row=i + 1, column=j + 1, sticky=W)
        Button(top, text='Згенерувати випадково', font=("Arial", 18),
               command=random_gen).grid(row=1, column=int(ent.get()) + 1, pady=10)

app = App()
app.window()
Nmax = len(app.tabl)
```

Comment: так как вы в конструкторе присваиваете переменной tabl значение none,  то выбивает ошибку (Typeerror) типо объект None не может иметь длину len

Comment: @Ivan нужно ведь сначала запустить код, я к тому коммент и делал. В ответ добавил запуск window()

Comment: у меня выбивает ошибку Invalid literal int with base 10
И ругается на все строчки, где есть int(ent.get())
Вы не знаете как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Ivan покажите полный лог ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ivangulak/PycharmProjects/python_lab/DM/main.py", line 64, in <module>
    app.window()
  File "/Users/ivangulak/PycharmProjects/python_lab/DM/main.py", line 43, in window
    for m in range(int(ent.get())):
AttributeError: module 'ent' has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Ivan подключаемый модуль ent не имеет функции get(), проверьте то, что вы вызываете

Answer (score 2):

После вызова `randomn_gen` (например по клику на кнопки), вызов `Nmax = len(tabl)` вернет значение таблицы, до этого момент в `tabl` не будет значения.

```
# Глобальная переменная
tabl = None                         # <<<<<<<<<<<

def create_tabl_random(n):
    tabl = []
    for i in range(n):
        tabl.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            tabl[i].append(random.randint(0, 1))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j:
                tabl[i][j] = 0
            else:
                tabl[i][j] = tabl[j][i]
    return tabl


def window():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.title("Матриця суміжності")
    top.minsize(700, 600)

    def random_gen():
        # Инициация глобальной переменной
        global tabl
        tabl = create_tabl_random(int(ent.get()))
        for i in range(int(ent.get())):
            for j in range(int(ent.get())):
                list_ent[i][j].insert(END, tabl[i][j])

    r = 1
    c = 1
    for m in range(int(ent.get())):
        lab = Label(top, text=m, bg="papaya whip", font=("Arial", 18), width=3)
        lab.grid(row=r, column=0)
        r += 1
    for n in range(int(ent.get())):
        lab = Label(top, text=n, bg="papaya whip", font=("Arial", 18), width=3)
        lab.grid(row=0, column=c)
        c += 1
    list_ent = []
    for i in range(int(ent.get())):
        list_ent.append([])
        for j in range(int(ent.get())):
            list_ent[i].append(Entry(top, font=("Arial", 18), bg="floral white", width=3))
            list_ent[i][j].grid(row=i + 1, column=j + 1, sticky=W)
    Button(top, text='Згенерувати випадково', font=("Arial", 18), command=random_gen).grid(row=1, column=int(ent.get()) + 1, pady=10)
```

Comment: Это же ничего не даст. В Nmax будет 0 и всё.

Comment: @gil9red теперь такая ошибка TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: @Ivan, вы вызвали `len(tabl)` до вызова `random_gen()`, поэтому в `tabl` еще было `None`